# Pandas Delete/replace Specific Value according to location in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, signal-processing

How do I target a specific row and column and delete or replace that value with `NaN` with pandas data frames?

I have this data Filtering Problem.
I wrote my magnetic sensors data in a CSV file, but **now I have to find the outliers and count them** in order to compare diffrent location on an object.

As soon as I start moving the sensor the values jump all over the place. So there is a connction beweeen the values. I cannot simply assume my values are fixed and say bigger/smaller than x is an outlier.
As Method of choice I inspect the diffrence betweeen the values on one axis/column. If the difference is too big, it's an outlier.
Now I have used the pandas Library to read the data from my CSV file and I would like to delete the data in grey. Since I have three axis, so three columns, I cannot simply drop one row, because that I only want count the outliers. Deletion of rows would result in deletion of non outliers.

My Idea is now to remove the outliers and compare lengths of the Series or replace the outliers with NaN and count NaNs. For that I would have to remember all outliers somehow and target them specifically.

This is a graph of my values and following is the code without the visualization part
[image: Data with Outliers]

```
def analyse( filename):
df = pd.read_csv(filename, float_precision='round_trip') # df= dfframe
listOfNames=["X", "Y", "Z"]
df.to_csv('temp.csv', index=False)
upperBorder=1
for x in listOfNames:
    sigma=df[x].diff().std() # Calculates the standardderivation of difference of a Dataframe element compared with element in previous row). https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html
    df['is Noise'+str(x)] = df[x].diff().apply(lambda val: 'Green' if val < upperBorder*sigma and val > (-1)*upperBorder*sigma else 'Grey' )
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: Any problem with `df.loc[df['is Noise'+str(x)], x] = math.nan`? This selects only the lines where `x` is an outlier and sets only the `x` column to nan.

Comment: No. This is fine. Thanks